# Show value from BLE device to Heart Widget in flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I want to show my readings that are coming from Esp32 to my Heart Widget that is displayed on HomeScreen.
I used the [example code](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example) of flutter_blue package to check whether readings are coming to the app, but I am having difficulty understanding the code as I am new to Flutter.

My Bluetooth Connection Screen looks like this, which shows the list of nearby BLE devices

[image]

When I press Connect Button it goes to this screen showing the services, descriptors, and MTU size.

[image]

As clearly seen in the picture that the last service is getting values from ESP32, I want to show the values under Characteristic to show in Heart Rate Widget, where 96 is written. But I can't understand how I should display the value of the characteristic on this screen and not on the above screen.

[image]

These are the values that I am getting on the console as well, which are correct. I just want that when I press the connect button of ESP32, it should connect instantly and instead of going to 2nd screen it should go to the home screen and show values inside the heart rate widget

[image]

My code for Bluetooth Scanning Devices Screen is:

```
// Copyright 2017, Paul DeMarco.
// All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'BluetoothConnectBand.dart';
import 'widgets.dart';


class FlutterBlueApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor:Colors.lightBlue ,
       body: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);

          }),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BluetoothOffScreen({Key key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      appBar:AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        elevation: 0,
      leading:IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return BluetoothConnectBand();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
              size: 200.0,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            Text(
              'Bluetooth Adapter is ${state != null ? state.toString().substring(15) : 'not available'}.',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .primaryTextTheme
                  .subhead
                  ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Connect Band",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return BluetoothConnectBand();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () =>
            FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4)),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      height: size.height * 0.4,
                      width: size.width,
                      color: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/bluetooth.png',
                      )),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Scanning Available Devices...",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  //Expanded(child:_buildListViewOfDevices()),
                ],
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(d.name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(d.id.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                      stream: d.state,
                      initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data ==
                            BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                          return FlatButton(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                            ),
                            child: Text('Connected'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        DeviceScreen(device: d))),
                          );
                        }
                        return Text(snapshot.data.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),);
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                      result: r,
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        r.device.connect();
                        return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                      })),
                    ),
                  )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (c, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance
                    .startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4)),
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothDevice device;

  List<int> _getRandomBytes() {
    final math = Random();
    return [
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255)
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    return services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
        service: s,
        characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
            .map(
              (c) => CharacteristicTile(
            characteristic: c,
            onReadPressed: () => c.read(),
            onWritePressed: () async {
              await c.write(_getRandomBytes(), withoutResponse: true);
              await c.read();
            },
            onNotificationPressed: () async {
              await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
              await c.read();
            },
            descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                .map(
                  (d) => DescriptorTile(
                descriptor: d,
                onReadPressed: () => d.read(),
                onWritePressed: () => d.write(_getRandomBytes()),
              ),
            )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
            .toList(),
      ),
    )
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(device.name),
        actions: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
            stream: device.state,
            initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
            builder: (c, snapshot) {
              VoidCallback onPressed;
              String text;
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
                  onPressed = () => device.disconnect();
                  text = 'DISCONNECT';
                  break;
                case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                  onPressed = () => device.connect();
                  text = 'CONNECT';
                  break;
                default:
                  onPressed = null;
                  text = snapshot.data.toString().substring(21).toUpperCase();
                  break;
              }
              return FlatButton(
                  onPressed: onPressed,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .primaryTextTheme
                        .button
                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
              stream: device.state,
              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                    ? Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                    : Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
                title: Text(
                    'Device is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]}.'),
                subtitle: Text('${device.id}'),
                trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: device.isDiscoveringServices,
                  initialData: false,
                  builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                    index: snapshot.data ? 1 : 0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        onPressed: () => device.discoverServices(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          width: 18.0,
                          height: 18.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: device.mtu,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                title: Text('MTU Size'),
                subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () => device.requestMtu(223),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: device.services,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code for Widgets is the same as written in the [code example](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/example/lib/widgets.dart), I have only changed main file for my UI.

Code for Heart Rate Widget:

```
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: size.height * 0.190,
              width: size.width * 0.80,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
              child: Card(
                color: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
                elevation: 5,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const SpinKitPumpingHeart(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                        //Image.asset(
                        //   'assets/images/heart_button.png',
                        // ),
                        ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: size.width * 0.80,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '96',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                              fontSize: 19,
                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              height: 1.4736842105263157,
                            ),
                            textHeightBehavior: TextHeightBehavior(
                                applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Heart Rate',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                              fontSize: 19,
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              height: 1.2777777777777777,
                            ),
                            textHeightBehavior: TextHeightBehavior(
                                applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Where are you printing your heartbeat in code that is showing in logcat can you guide cant find it.

Comment: This is link to widget.dart, i changed it a bit for my UI. But it is exactly similar to the example code for the package
https://www.codepile.net/pile/MZkAVBRW
where I have commented down "// this is where value is printing on console"
in the code is the line where value is printing on the console

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: Problem solved @AmitKumar

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to use a Provider.
With one class

```
    import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
    
    class BlueDevice extends ChangeNotifier {
      /// Internal, private state of the Device.
      BluetoothDevice _device;
      BluetoothService _service;
    
      /// Device metrics
      int heartRate;
    
    ...
    
    /// Adds device to model. This is the only way to modify the device from outside.
      void add(BluetoothDevice d) async {
        _device = d;
        await _device.connect();
        _device.discoverServices();
        _device.services.listen((lista) {
          for (int iService = 0; iService < lista.length; iService++) {
            if (lista[iService].uuid.toString().startsWith("YOUR UUID")) {
              _service = lista[iService];
            }
          }
        });
        // This line tells [Model] that it should rebuild the widgets that
        // depend on it.
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      void read() async {
        List<List> values = [];
        if (_service != null) {
          for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in _service.characteristics) {
            values.add(await c.read());
          }
        }
        heartRate = values[0][0];
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

need to create the provider

```
    class FlutterBlueApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            // In this app, BlueDevice is implemented as a ChangeNotifier,
            // which calls for the use of ChangeNotifierProvider.
            create: (context) => BlueDevice(),
            child: Scaffold(...
```

and you may use it with a consumer

```
    Consumer<BlueDevice>(
              builder: (context, blue, child) => Text(blue.heartRate.toString(),
         //'96', THIS WAS THE VALUE
       style: TextStyle(
       fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
       fontSize: 19,
       color: const Color(0xffffffff),
       fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
       height: 1.4736842105263157,
       ),
```